# Single line exception to GCC_WARN_SHADOW = YES?

Tags: objective-c, clang

I have this code:

```
id error;
// a bunch of stuff, including using error
Finalization finalization = ^(int status) {
    id error; // <--- Declaration shadows a local variable
    // a bunch of stuff, using error
}
// a bunch of stuff, using error
```

I use `GCC_WARN_SHADOW` because it's what I want in every case in my code except this one. In this case, it gives me a warning that I want to suppress.

Is there a way to suppress this one shadow warning without turning off `GCC_WARN_SHADOW` **or** renaming the inner error to something else? Some way to mark that declaration of error?

I'm using clang with Xcode 4, if it matters.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't rename the inner `error`?

Comment: No, that's been my solution to this point. But it's slightly inelegant, it that it means that any code moved from inside to outside the block needs to be modified. Most of the time, this is fine, but as far as I know the Cocoa convention for NSError instances to be called error not (for instance) error2 or finalizationError.

Comment: Maybe I should tag this question as pedantic, too? :)

Comment: `error` is the convention only because there's rarely a better name for the error. :P `e` is common too, or a more descriptive variable name such as `finalizationError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as a matter of opinion, it's really bad karma to shadow a local variable within an inner block (its bad enough shadowing a global variable in a function). Now "error" can take two different values within a function, and until whomever is reading your code figures it out, they will bang their head quite incessantly. I have seen this issue in real life among paid professionals developing apps. I really suggest renaming the inner error variable.

Answering your question, you can [use the GCC/clang compiler pragma to suppress a warning](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-via-pragmas).

Comment: I disagree with your opinion here, as the whole point of naming it the same thing is it's the same concept. Which error shouldn't matter, as the only reason you'd use this is for GCD blocks where the outer `error` is useless to the inner code. But your answer is of course correct, and I think your opinion is correct for most other variable shadowing. :)